# Manually specify tomcat deploy directory for maven command line

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment

I know that there is a way to manually specify the deploy directory for maven but I forget what it is.

I think it is something like -DmavenTomcatHome=/opt/tom2

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

This was the command I ended up using:

mvn -e sakai:deploy -U -Dmaven.tomcat.home=/opt/sakai10tomcat

The bit I needed was the -Dmaven.tomcat.home.